# Probabilistic subset intersection

Tags: combinatorics, probabilistic-method

Let $\left \{ \left ( A_{i},B_{i} \right ),1\leq i\leq h \right \}$ be a family of pairs of subsets of the set of
integers such that $\left | A_{i} \right |=k$ for all $ i$ and $\left | B_{i} \right |=l$ for all $i$, $A_{i}\cap B_{i}=\emptyset$ and
$(A_{i}\cap B_{j})\cup (A_{j}\cap B_{i})\neq \emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$ . Prove that $$h< \left(\dfrac{k+l}{k}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{k+l}{l}\right)^l.$$
[Source: The probabilistic method, Alon and Spencer, p.11]

The idea should be to set up an event with probability $\left(\dfrac{k}{k+l}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{l}{k+l}\right)^l$, but it's not clear how to do this.

(This question was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695875/prove-that-h-fracklklkkll), but the answer posted is not understandable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p=\frac{k}{k+l},q=1-p=\frac{l}{k+l}$.

Let $Z$ be the finite set $\cup_{k}A_k\cup B_k$. Consider a
random  experiment $E$ whose probability of success is $p$. Repeat
this experiment independently as many times as there are elements in
$Z$ ; this produces experiments $(E_{z})_{z\in Z}$.

Next, for $1\leq i \leq h$ consider the event $C_i$ : “$E_z$ succeeds
for every $z\in A_i$ and fails for every $z\in B_i$”.

I claim that the $C_i$ are mutually incompatible. Indeed, let $i\neq j$
be two indices in $[1,h]$. By hypothesis, we have for example 
$A_i\cap B_j \neq \emptyset$ ; let $t\in A_i\cap B_j$. Then $E_t$
succeeds if $C_i$ holds, and fails if $C_j$ holds. This shows my claim.
It follows that $P(\cup_{i=1}^{h}C_i)=\sum_{i=1}^h P(C_i)$. Now,
the union $\cup_{i=1}^{h}C_i$ does not exhaust the whole probabilistic
universe we are considering (consider for example the case when 
every $E_z$ succeeds). It follows that $\sum_{i=1}^h P(C_i)<1$. Now
each $C_i$ occurs with probability $p^kq^l$, so $hp^kq^l <1$ as wished.

Comment: What do you mean by "$S_t$ holds for $t\in A_i$"?

Comment: But the elements of $A_i$ might be greater than $h$. Say, $1000\in A_i$ and $h=10$. Then your statement $x_t\in A_t$ for any $t\in A_i$ would say that $x_{1000}\in A_{1000}$, which doesn't make sense because there's only $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_{10}$.

Comment: @simmons Corrected now, thanks.